# What is the appropriate command line to connect through SSH?

Tags: command-line, ssh, connection

I would like to connect to my remote machine through SSH command line, but I don't know what are the appropriate terminal commands.

I always get an error "connection refused".

Comment: Excelent [how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html) on Ubuntu official help. Also type `man ssh` for manual pages.

Comment: What commands are you using that give the error?

Answer (score 2):

Command is

```
ssh -l username server_ip_address
```

or

```
ssh username@server_ip_address
```

If server refuse connection maybe is some different problem. 
Some firewall settings ...

Comment: I agree on the commands, but can you expand on the possible problems? Firewall, wrong pass, certificates, etc.

Comment: First try with `nmap server_ip_address`. Is server is up with ssh service ready to accept connection you will see `PORT STATE SERVICE 22/tcp  open  ssh`. If port is open server is ready. Do you have root privilege for server?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the ssh server `sshd` is not installed in Ubuntu by default.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

run on both machines will get `ssh` and `sshd` installed.

**WARNING:** sshd is not installed by default for good reason, it has the potential to open your system to any black-hat hacker or bot on the internet especially if you have weak passwords or firewalls. You should understand the security hole that you'll open before you open it.

Comment: you don't need openssh-server on the client machine, and openssh-client is not necessary on the server. Just make sure you have openssh-server installed and running on the server and openssh-client installed on the client.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must be sure that the ssh server you want to connect is running. To do this, try typing:

```
telnet server_ip 22
```

where 22 is the default port of the `ssh protocol`. If the port is different, you must change it. 
If the server replies to you, you can connect this way:

```
ssh <username>@server_ip -p 22
```

is the user who has permission to access the server via ssh. 
The `-p 22` argument can omit it if the port is the default, or if you use a different port you have to use it.